# Escape all single quotes in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, escaping

Instead of escaping each `'` in text, is there any way to escape them all at once, something like this:

```
insert into table1(data) values(@'it's a string, it's got some single quotes')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
insert into table1(data) values
($$it's a string, it's got some single quotes$$)
```

[Dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)

> A dollar-quoted string constant consists of a dollar sign ($), an optional "tag" of zero or more characters, another dollar sign, an arbitrary sequence of characters that makes up the string content, a dollar sign, the same tag that began this dollar quote, and a dollar sign